# How can I add In App Purchases in Expo SDK

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to add IAP with Expo for subscriptions (monthly).

I follow this document (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/)

I added library with this code `yarn add expo-in-app-purchases` and there is no issue.

The app crashed when I write import code 
`import * as InAppPurchases from 'expo-in-app-purchases';`

error is blow
`Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.`

my package.json file:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.11.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-in-app-purchases": "^9.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "npm": "^6.14.10",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.16.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Do you have any idea for this?
Finally, Is there any demo on snack or github etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for updating the question. It looks to me as you are in an expo managed workflow. In order to make use of Expos IAP you would need to expo eject and configure react native unimodules.

Give some thought before ejecting and research it. However expo makes the process straight forward, however once you've ejected you cant go back.
https://docs.expo.io/expokit/eject/

Comment: I added my package.json. I dont use expo bare. I use standart Expo

Comment: I see thanks, I have updated the answer above.

Comment: Thanks your response. I have to eject Expo because I must add IAP. I mark your answer is accept answer

Comment: @HasanRızaUzuner I have my Expo managed app and need to add expo-in-app-purchases and use in app purchases... is not possible to use it in managed workflow? When you eject expo you get native xcode and android studio projects? or how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Actually with eas / expo-dev-client it's possible to add IAP with managed workflow.
I published a [medium guide here.](https://medium.com/@jonathan.payet/expo-in-app-purchase-for-managed-app-cdcd643de28d)

Comment: But this requires EAS Priority subscription which is $29/mo

Comment: @EmreSülün it is free now

Comment: Yes but at the time of the question this option wasnt around